# Geolocating Ruby and Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I built an application on rails and Javascript were the users can upload pictures and I save them to Amazon S3 using paperclip. I added latitude and longitude to each of the pictures saved in the database. What I need to do is get the user's current geo location (I'm already getting this but in the javascript side) and filter in my database the pictures that are within 1 mile of radius of the user's location, and send back those pictures. I'm really confused on how to do this, I guess geolocator gem can be helpful but I'm new to it. I appreciate if someone can give me a hand with this.

Model

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_attached_file :image, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>",:thumb =>     "100x100>" }

    validates_attachment    :image, 
                :presence => true,
                :content_type => { :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/ },
                :size => { :less_than => 2.megabyte }

    def image_url
        image.url
    end
end
```

Controller

```
class UploadsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    render json: Upload.all.to_json(:methods => [:image_url])
  end

  def new
    @upload = Upload.new
  end

  def create
    @upload = Upload.create(upload_params)
    if @upload.save
      render json: { message: "success" }, :status => 200
    else
      #need to send an error header, otherwise Dropzone
      #  will not interpret the response as an error:
      render json: { error: @upload.errors.full_messages.join(',')}, :status => 400
    end         
  end

  private
  def upload_params
    params.require(:upload).permit(:image, :latitude, :longitude)
  end
end
```

Javascript used to get current geo location

```
x = $("#demo")[0];
        function getLocation() {
         if (navigator.geolocation) {
         navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
         } 
         else {
         x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
         }
        }
        function showPosition(position) {
            var lat = position.coords.latitude;
            var long = position.coords.longitude;
        x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + lat + 
        "<br>Longitude: " + long; 

        $('#upload_latitude').attr('value', lat)
        $('#upload_longitude').attr('value', long)
        }
        getLocation()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also another geolocator gem called [geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) I personally haven't used it, but it looks pretty good documentation wise.

I found it when I was looking up [I18n](http://www.sitepoint.com/go-global-rails-i18n/)